Failed to deploy application version Environment named ********* is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready
Hi i am trying to revert back to the old application verison that i have but when i try to i get this message"Failed to deploy application version
Environment named ****** is in an invalid state for this operation. Must be Ready..
so not exactly sure what to do
thanks
-I have tired to restart the app service and it doesnt do anything
-I have tired to upload the pervious version manually but that did not work either
-nothing is building at the moment
-restarted the tomcat server

the Health is showing "Ok" green


so i went into the configuration from the elastic bean stalk and changed it to 0 like you said but it would not let me save anything when i try to save it says invaild state
